# How to write a cron expression spanning multiple hours with an arbitrary start minute

Tags: cron, scheduled-tasks

I want to write a cron expression for every minute from 10:45 am to 11:30 am. Is there a way to write such an expression. I understand that if I set starting minute as 45, it doesn't schedule anything for 11-11:30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You'll need to break it up into two cron jobs. [45-59 10 * * *](https://crontab.guru/#45-59_10_*_*_*) and [0-30 11 * * *](https://crontab.guru/#0-30_11_*_*_*).